# Content Uri crashing my app but file Uri is working

Tags: java, android, android-studio

code:

```
    if (fileSizeInKB > 2000 && goFurther) {
         Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Method.mContext,
                                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider",file);
                        Log.d("hiddenFileChecking2",String.valueOf(uri));
                        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                        retriever.setDataSource(Method.mContext,uri); //not working
                        //retriever.setDataSource(Method.mContext,Uri.fromFile(file)); //its working
                        String hasVideo = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_HAS_VIDEO);
                        Log.d("hiddenHasVideo",hasVideo);
                        boolean isVideo = "yes".equals(hasVideo);
                        if (isVideo) {
                            Constant.allHiddenMediaList.add(file);
                        }
                }
```

logcat error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ContentResolver android.content.Context.getContentResolver()' on a null object reference
    at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:168)
```

I want to use content uri inside `setDataSource`. But I am getting that error. When I use `file uri` app crashing in `android 7-nougat`. How can I use content uri inside `setDataSource`.
**what I want:** I want to find all video file not using extensions. for example: I change the extension "`helloWorld.mp4`" to "`helloWorld.pdf`". Now I want to detect the file("`helloWorld.pdf`") as video.

Comment: The used Context is null. Not valid. Check for null before use.

Comment: same thing working in file uri. How can I check before use?

Comment: `if(Method.mContext==null) return;` Display also a toast to inform the user.

Comment: If I do so, I won't be able to check any file. But I want to check all the file.

Comment: It does not matter what you want. As long as you use an invalid context, a context that is null, there is not much to do.

Comment: How Can I avoid this and get what I want?